# Sonarqube Sqale Rating based on Quality Gate

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, static-analysis, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I am using Sonaqube 4.5.6 with Sqale plugin. On running analysis from Jenkins for Java and UI projects, Sonarqube gives me a Sqale rating. I have set quality gates for each profile with the below threshold.

```
 Blocker Issues > 0
 Critical Issues > 0
 Coverage > 60%
```

How do I modify Sqale to reflect the quality gate?
If a project does not pass a quality gate, Squale rating should be less than A and red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but that's just not how the SQALE rating works. That rating is based on the time estimated to remediate your code versus the estimated time to write it into its current state.

SQALE model's simply not about calling attention to the worst offenders.

Comment: thanks Ann. I would stick to quality gates then. Appreciate your time.